# Wolfram Alpha equation I couldn't find anywhere

Tags: functions, derivatives, wolfram-alpha

I was just playing around with Wolfram Alpha and n-th derivatives of functions, and I found this....[n-th derivative of W(x) equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV7tx.png)

As you can see, there are some weird functions. I found most of them in the bottom-right corner. However, that Y function isn't anywhere. I typed in that, and it returned nothing. My phone is really laggy so I couldn't see how Mathematica interprets it. Does anybody know the name of that function?

Comment: Likely to be a Bessel function of the second kind http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you, it seems like it is, however, it isn't multivariable. I will try to find something else related to it.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html for the expression of the n-th derivative of $W(x)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, I saw all the versions of it, but this one I screenshoted is the freest of all of them. I just want to find out the name of the function. It's apparently some multivariable version of Bessel function of the second kind.